# Swift Share sheet in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a class with UIView and want to share a URL link, what is the proper way of adding the share sheet in UIView?

My current code is attempting to call the share sheet via a button click:

```
//share app
@IBAction func shareAppBtn(sender: AnyObject ) {
    print("shareAppBtn tapped")
    let myWebsite = NSURL(string:"http://www.google.com/")

    guard let url = myWebsite else {
        print("nothing found")
        return
    }

    let shareItems:Array = [url]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.window?.rootViewController!.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I tried to use the root view of the current UIView but I receive an error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIActivityViewController: on <RAMAnimatedTabBarController.RAMAnimatedTabBarController: which is already presenting <SideMenu.UISideMenuNavigationController: Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIAlertController:)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `presentViewController`on the rootViewController? Try it without the `self.window?.rootViewController!.`

Comment: I had initially tried that actually, but that gave me an error since I'm calling it from a UIView, the error is:  `Use of unresolved identifier 'presentViewController'`

Comment: You have to call it on a viewController, yes. Your button and your UIView and somehow in a viewController?

Comment: My button is inside a UIView, it cannot be inside a viewController for a few reasons.

Comment: Maybe this threads helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622736/using-presentviewcontroller-from-uiview

Answer (score 0):

You don't add a share sheet in a UIView. A share sheet is a view controller and as such it always needs another view controller to provide a context for presentation.

You have done this by using the root view of the current view, which is already presenting a navigation controller `UISideMenuNavigationController`.

Try presenting from that context:

```
sideMenuNavigationController.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that did not work, I get an `Use of unresolved identifier 'sideMenuNavigationController'` error. I think I get the concept of not being able to call the share sheet because I'm in a UIView, this would be easier if it were another view controller.

Comment: Please check how that navigation controller actually is named in your code. That was just a guess coming from the context of your error message.

Comment: Ahh my bad, trying to call the Navigation Controller that has the root view for `SideMenu` class is `UISideMenuNavigationController`, however I get the same error using that as well: `Use of unresolved identifier 'UISideMenuNavigationController'`

Comment: Somewhere in your view hierarchy there is a UISideMenuNavigationController that seems to be on the top of the view hierarchy. Can you try find it and present from that view controller?

Comment: `UISideMenuNavigationController` is a Navigation controller that I created in Story Board which has a root view for `SideMenu`, how do I present this Navigation Controller inside my `SideMenu` UIView?