# How to present programmatically a view controller from a UIVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ibaction, swiftmessages

I am using a Class which is a subclass of `MessageView` ([Swift Message Library](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages)) which is inherit from `UIView`. Inside, I have a `UIButton` and I want to present programmatically another `ViewController` through it.

Here is my code below :

```
import Foundation
import SwiftMessages
import UIKit

class MyClass: MessageView {

    var hideBanner: (() -> Void)?


    @IBAction func helpButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController") as! NewViewController
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    @IBAction func tryAgainButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        hideBanner?()
    }

    open override func awakeFromNib() {

    }

}
```

I have tried this, but it is not working since the `UIView` do not have the present method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using presentViewController from UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15622736/using-presentviewcontroller-from-uiview)

Comment: I think it's a bad pattern to do so. You should use delegation which conformed from view controller than you can use present method to present your controller.

Comment: Hope you are not struggling with this.. the answers given focus on the idea of the view communicating to the controller that something needs to happen. The controller should take the actual action to make it happen. Don't forget to upvote the answers.

Answer (score 2):

First get top `ViewController` using this. Then you can present your `viewController`.

```
if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
        topController = presentedViewController
    }

    // topController now can use for present.
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController") as! NewViewController
    topController.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This can be somewhat brittle in a number of ways. Multiple storyboards, navigation controllers, etc. Walking the controller/view hierarchy can get very complex.

Comment: This one worked for me, had to use self.present.......   in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`.present` is a method in `UIViewController` class, that's the reason you cannot present view controller from `UIView` class.

To achieve this, get the root view controller and present the controller as follows:

```
let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let viewController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! YourViewController
let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController") as! NewViewController
        viewController .present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks but MyClass still does not have the present method:
"Value of type 'MyClass' has no member 'present'"

Comment: Replace self with `viewController ` as written in my updated answer. Sorry for typo.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS convention is that only a `ViewController`s presents another `ViewController`.

So the answers above - where the `View` is finds the current `ViewController` via `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?....` *will work* but is very much an anti-pattern.

The preferred way would be:

- Your `MyClass` view has presentation code only
- You must have a ViewController which has a reference to this `MyClass` view
- This ViewController has the `@IBAction func tryAgainButtonPressed`
- From there, you can present the next ViewController

Answer (score 1):

Try this **#simple** code.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftMessages
import UIKit

class MyClass: MessageView {

var hideBanner: (() -> Void)?


@IBAction func helpButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController") as! NewViewController
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func tryAgainButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    hideBanner?()
}

open override func awakeFromNib() {

}

}
```

Comment: Would be better if you show the Controller logic driving the storyboard calls. That ought to come from the Controller not the view.  Using the closure object to manage the callback is useful to notify the controller object when to make that new presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example code using delegation pattern.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
  var yourView: MyClass // may be outlet

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        yourView.delegate = self
    }

}

protocol MyClassDelegate:class {
    func tryAgainButtonDidPressed(sender: UIButton)
}

class MyClass: MessageView {

  weak var delegate: MyClassDelegate?


   @IBAction func tryAgainButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.tryAgainButtonDidPressed(sender: sender)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by two ways

- Protocol
- By giving reference of that view controller to the view when you are initializing view

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply. `MessageView` already provides a `buttonTapHandler` callback for you:

```
/// An optional button tap handler. The `button` is automatically
/// configured to call this tap handler on `.TouchUpInside`.
open var buttonTapHandler: ((_ button: UIButton) -> Void)?

@objc func buttonTapped(_ button: UIButton) {
    buttonTapHandler?(button)
}

/// An optional button. This buttons' `.TouchUpInside` event will automatically
/// invoke the optional `buttonTapHandler`, but its fine to add other target
/// action handlers can be added.
@IBOutlet open var button: UIButton? {
    didSet {
        if let old = oldValue {
            old.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(MessageView.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        if let button = button {
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MessageView.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }
}
```

which is automatically invoked for any button you connect to the `button` outlet. So the recommended method for presenting another view controller is to have the presenting view controller configure the presentation logic in this callback:

```
messageView.tapHandler = { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "newViewController") as! NewViewController
    strongSelf.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

If your view has more than one button, you can handle them all through `buttonTapHandler` since it takes a `button` argument. You just need to configure the target-action mechanism for each button:

```
otherButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MessageView.buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Or you can add one callback for each button by duplicating the above pattern.