# How can i goto UIViewController storyboard from UIView

Tags: ios, swift

**UIView**

```
import UIKit

class TridHeaderBar: UIView {


    @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {

    }

}
```

I would like to go a ViewController from this UIView.
I have tried below code

```
let ctrl = FirstViewController()
self.present(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate. Better look this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623730/1659566

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Callback** function also to get tap action on your parrentViewController:

1) Declare callback function into your view:

```
var callback:(() -> Void)?
```

> You can also pass any value from your view like (var callback:((String) -> Void)?). I take string here you can pass as you want.
>
> and in button action call this function like this (callback?("i am passing string here"))

2) Call this function in your IBAction of button:

```
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
     callback?()
}
```

3) Write callback function closure in your parrentViewControler:

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myCustomView: MyView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       viewTapped()
    }

   func viewTapped() {
      myCustomView.callback = { [unowned self] 
          //you will get button tap action here
          let ctrl = FirstViewController()
          self.present(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: getting this error where i have added ParentViewContrller  (Cannot assign value of type '(_) -> ()' to type '(() -> Void)?')

Comment: I edit my answer please check, I remove (_ in) from closure.

Answer (score 4):

You can use various methods to reach your goal, one of them(and one the best) is use **delegation**.

So first you need to define your delegate:

```
protocol MYViewDelegate: class {
  func buttonTap(sender: MYView)
}
```

Then in your view:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    weak var delegate: MYViewDelegate?

    @IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.buttonTap(sender: self)
    }
}
```

Now you set the parent view controller where you custom view as **delegate** of you custom view and the job is done.

```
class MYParentViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var myCustomView: MyView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       myCustomView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension MYParentViewController: MYViewDelegate {
    func buttonTapped(sender: MYView) {
       let ctrl = FirstViewController()
       self.present(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```